# SQL Two columns of guids no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, guid

I am learning SQL by watching YouTube and I am trying to achieve the following.
I have a table with three Columns

```
Inspection Guid, SensorData Guid, DateTime
```

I want to get a table of Inspection Guid, SensorDataGuid, DateTime but with no duplicate Inspection Guids.

From (I have shortened the Guids for convenience)

```
6E814118    DA875776    2016-05-25 14:59:17.523
6E814118    BAEB255D    2016-05-25 14:59:17.523
4B7D4E90    BB717852    2016-05-25 14:58:46.260
06BB9435    2321EDD6    2016-05-25 14:58:16.870
06BB9435    D4168F8B    2016-05-25 14:58:16.870
8D9A8502    3EED26BE    2016-05-25 14:57:47.400
5C9AA885    77D342DD    2016-05-25 14:57:15.217
5C9AA885    43DEF213    2016-05-25 14:57:15.217
```

To

```
6E814118    DA875776    2016-05-25 14:59:17.523
4B7D4E90    BB717852    2016-05-25 14:58:46.260
06BB9435    2321EDD6    2016-05-25 14:58:16.870
8D9A8502    3EED26BE    2016-05-25 14:57:47.400
5C9AA885    77D342DD    2016-05-25 14:57:15.217
```

Sorted by date time.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: There is a logic issue here - how do you decide which SensorDataGuid to drop when those are different for a duplicate InspectionGuid? (For example, the first row with InspectionGuid `6E814118` )

Comment: The first Inspection / SensorData Guid pair is fine.

Comment: I do not know why the datetimes are the same between the two rows with the same Inspection IDs. They should be slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE `ROW_NUMBER()` to choose the first GUID based on `DATE` and then `ORDER BY` to display.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        SELECT [Inspection Guid], 
               [SensorData Guid], 
               [DateTime],
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Inspection Guid] 
                                  ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC) rn
        FROM YourTable
      ) T
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC
```

Comment: Note that what @Johnny wants is only possible if records with the same Inspection Guid will automatically have the same SensorData Guid and DateTime. Otherwise, you can't display just the distinct Inspection Guids, because how would it decide which other data to show?

Comment: @GendoIkari  You are right I tought was a same value

Comment: Yes, it still duplicates, you guys are right. I forgot to include that I wanted the top N number of rows as the database is large.

Comment: @Johnny why you mean duplicates? did you try the row_number version?

Comment: Thank the gods for you sir. PARTITION was misspelled and there needs to be a comma after [DateTime], ROW_NUMBER. I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not actually possible as asked.

Take for example these 2 records:

```
06BB9435    2321EDD6    2016-05-25 14:58:16.870
06BB9435    D4168F8B    2016-05-25 14:58:16.870
```

If you only want to show `06BB9435` once, how would you decide which other piece of data to show? You have to decide which date to show for each duplicate GUID. If you wanted something like the most recent date, and the alphabetically highest SensorData, then you could do this:

```
SELECT [Inspection Guid], MAX([SensorData Guid]), MAX([DateTime])
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY [Inspection Guid]
ORDER BY MAX([DateTime]) DESC
```

Comment: The most recent date would work perfectly. But I get Column "InspectionSensorData.CreatedTimeStamp" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Johnny Sorry, fixed the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: This is really close! The MAX function appears to be interfering with the SensorDataID, selecting the GUID with the Max value as opposed to the matching time stamp.

Comment: MAX([SensorData Guid]) seems to mix the SensorDataID selecting independently with respect to the latest DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH duplicates AS
(
    SELECT
        [Inspection Guid],
        [SensorData Guid],
        [DateTime],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
            PARTITION BY [Inspection Guid], [DateTime]
            ORDER BY [SensorData Guid]
        ) AS rn
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM duplicates
WHERE rn = 1
```

The partition by 2 fields `[Inspection Guid]`, `[DateTime]` makes sure that the partition for each date time is unique.